# Using Gdb debugger, how should I proceed to find out the cause of "Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault."

Tags: c++, gdb, gtk

Here is the backtrace of gdb,

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb7e78830 in Gtk::Widget::get_width () from /usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7e78830 in Gtk::Widget::get_width () from /usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
#1  0x08221d5d in sigc::bound_mem_functor0<bool, videoScreen>::operator() (this=0xb1c04714)
    at /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/mem_fun.h:1787`enter code here`
#2  0x08221d76 in sigc::adaptor_functor<sigc::bound_mem_functor0<bool, videoScreen> >::operator() (this=0xb1c04710)
    at /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h:251
#3  0x08221d96 in sigc::internal::slot_call0<sigc::bound_mem_functor0<bool, videoScreen>, bool>::call_it (rep=0xb1c046f8)
    at /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:103
#4  0xb7b1ed35 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#5  0xb73c6bb6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0xb28ff1f8 in ?? ()
#7  0xb647479c in __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb73c6446 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#9  0xb73c97e2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#10 0xb3d11af8 in ?? ()
#11 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

I figured out the line of crash,here is the code around that line.

```
1:currPicLoaded = 1;
2:int status = -1;
3:zoomedPicWidth = drawVideo1->get_width();
```

I figured out that above line is 3 is the cause of crash, but this line execute 5 times before crash.So I do not know why it does crash at 6th time.
PS : Above line of code is with in a thread which run continuously.

Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: Well there wouldn't be much sense in loops if each iteration produced the same result as the previous one. You need to debug the specific iteration that fails. This means stepping through code and examining variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Just before the crash , when I print the value of drawVideo1, it gives following output, \n                       (gdb) print drawVideo1
$1 = (Gtk::DrawingArea *) 0x919ab50
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ed5830 in Gtk::Widget::get_width () from /usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1                                                                                                                                 If the pointer has some valid memory address, why it is getting crash inside the library libgtkmm-2.4.so.1.

Comment: You probably want to examine the object pointed to by the offending variable too. Try `print *drawVideo1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how should I proceed

Your very first step should be to find out which instruction caused the `SIGSEGV`. Do this:

```
 (gdb) x/i $pc
```

The most likely cause is that your `drawVideo1` object is either dangling (has been deleted), or is corrupt in some other way.

Since you are apparently on Linux (you didn't say, but you should *always* say), the first tool to reach for for debugging "strange" problems like this is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).